# "Error processing Instruction 0: invalid program argument" while signing transfer transaction with PDA

Tags: transactions, rust, solana-program, pda

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?  I'm trying to transfer `SOL` from a `PDA` to the `to_account` but for some reason when I call it, fails with the following error message: `Error processing Instruction 0: invalid program argument` . According the solna cookbook (https://solanacookbook.com/references/accounts.html#how-to-sign-with-a-pda) it suppose to work, but I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

```
use solana_program::{
    account_info::next_account_info, account_info::AccountInfo, entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult, program::invoke_signed, pubkey::Pubkey, system_instruction,
};
use solana_program::rent::Rent;
use solana_program::sysvar::Sysvar;

entrypoint!(process_instruction);

fn process_instruction(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    _instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    let _initializer = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let pda = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let to_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let system_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;

    invoke_signed(
        &system_instruction::transfer(
            &pda.key,
            &to_account.key,
            100_000_000, // 0.1 SOL
        ),
        &[
            pda.clone(),
            to_account.clone(),
            system_program.clone(),
        ],
        &[&[b"wallet".as_ref(), &[255]]],
    )?;

    Ok(())
}
```

On the client side looks something like this:

```
const transaction = new Transaction().add(
  new TransactionInstruction({
    keys: [
      {pubkey: signer.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: false},
      {pubkey: programDerivedAddress, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},
      {pubkey: toAddress, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},
      {pubkey: SystemProgram.programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false}
    ],
    data: Buffer.from(new Uint8Array([])),
    programId: programId,
  })
);

await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    transaction,
    [signer],
);
```

Comment: The error can also be on how you build the instruction on the client, can you show us that piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved my problem by using the `try_borrow_mut_lamports` function instead of the `invoke_signed` and `&system_instruction::transfer`.

```
fn process_instruction(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    _instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    let _initializer = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let pda = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let to_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let system_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;

    **client_program_derived_account.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= 100_000_000;
    **to_account.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += 100_000_000;

    Ok(())
}
```

But would be nice to know why `invoke_signed` and `&system_instruction::transfer` doesn't work in my case.

Comment: took a look at the actual code that handles `system_instruction::transfer` and where that error comes from

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/9714cb37641a8679982ee70a976b09757555b23f/runtime/src/system_instruction_processor.rs#L184

looks like there's a check to make sure the from(`pda` account in your rust code) doesn't have any data. it looks like this check was introduced for protecting nonce accounts according to these prs/commits

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/7645
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/7645/commits/50534076799eec7898caebea0ed7bdb6bfedf56b

Comment: are you initializing the pda somewhere?

Comment: also in your `invoked_signed` there's no guarantee that the bump seed for the pda is going to be 255. pdas are found using the provided seeds ("wallet") and a bump seed that results in a publickey address that falls off the curve. the calculation will start at 255 but it could potentially be 254, 253, ... etc. whichever is the first the cause the publickey address to call off the curve. (mult bump_seeds can be valid but usually the highest one is used aka the "canonical" bump seed)

https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/pdas.html#facts

Answer (score 0):

assuming the rest of your rust code matches the solanacookbook example, I think you need to add the `instruction_data: &[u8]` parameter to execute_transaction() even if you're not going to do anything with it.

Comment: You are right, even when I added the `instruction_data` to my function, I got the same error.